# How to Navigate from a functional component, from a screen in a tab navigator, where that tab navigator is nested in a parent stack navigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

```
HomeStackNavigator(stack)
---HomeTabsNavigator(Tab)
   ---FirstTab(stack)
      ---CreatePost(screen)
      ---Posts(Tab)
         ---Following(screen)
         ---Feed(screen) <----- functional component in here, lets call it component1
   ---SecondTab
      ...
---Screen2
```

I want to be able to navigate from a functional component in the feed screen to screen 2. I've tried looking at the nested navigation docs in react native docs but no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the RootNavigation approach: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/

First you create a file at your directory root called `RootNavigation.js`
that looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

export function navigate(name, params) {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}
```

Then you pass the `navigationRef` as a ref to your `NavigationContainer`:

```
import * as RootNavigation from './RootNavigation';
// ...
<NavigationContainer ref={RootNavigation.navigationRef}>
   <HomeStackNavigator />
</NavigationContainer>
```

This allows you to navigate from anywhere.

Then you can do something like this in your `Feed` screen:

```
const Feed = () => {
    // ...
    <Button
      title="Navigate to SecondTab"
      onPress={() => RootNavigation.navigate('SecondTab')}
    />
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Worked exactly how I wanted it too, you are awesome!

Comment: how can i use CommonActions.reset() i with this method?