# how to access navigation outside of navigationcontainer

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

here I am trying to add navigation to my react-native project, the button register should navigate to the success page component but only issue is the button register exists out of the navigation container
here I am trying to access "navigation" outside of navigation container
here's the navigation container:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,Image,TouchableHighlight,TextInput,
  Button, } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import logo from './assets/logo4.png'
import logo2 from './assets/CFA_approved_prep_provider_RGB.png'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { enableScreens } from 'react-native-screens';
import { Component } from 'react';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import  { useRef } from "react";
import logo3 from './assets/logo3.png'



 
enableScreens();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm


import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';



    

export default function App() {
  const navigationRef = useRef(null)
  
  return (
    
    <View style={{flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      
      backgroundColor:'white',}}>
     
     
      
  
  
        <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
          
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="SplashScreen">
  <Stack.Screen name="SplashScreen" component={SplashScreen} /> 
  <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={Details} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SuccessPage" component={SuccessPage} />

        </Stack.Navigator>
        
</NavigationContainer>



  
        </View>
```

here I am trying to access it like that:

```
<View style={[{ width: "90%", margin: 10 }]}>
   <Button
      onPress={() => navigationRef.current.navigate("SuccessPage")}
      title="Register"
      
    />
</View>
```

that's the error:

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR3gF.jpg)

any idea what else can be done?

Comment: react navigation v4 or v5 ¿?

Comment: I have an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62941680/how-to-navigate-from-a-functional-component-from-a-screen-in-a-tab-navigator-w/62944296#62944296 that might be helpful for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can access navigation from outside of the NavigationContainer with the help of Navigation Ref.

Adding Navigation Container Ref

```
// App.js

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { navigationRef } from './RootNavigation';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>{/* ... */}</NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Creating and Using the Ref for navigating.

```
// RootNavigation.js

import { createNavigationContainerRef } from '@react-navigation/native';

export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef()

export function navigate(name, params) {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    navigationRef.navigate(name, params);
  }
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them
```