# Stack navigation in react native

Tags: reactjs, native

To create my app I followed some tutorials and I created this Stack navigator:

```
  const AppStack = createStackNavigator();
    const [user] =useContext(UserContext)

    return (
        <AppStack.Navigator headerMode="none">
            {user.isLoggedIn === null ? (
            <AppStack.Screen name="Loading" component={LoadingScreen} />

            ) : user.isLoggedIn ? (
            <AppStack.Screen name="Main" component={MainStackScreen} />

            ) : (
            <AppStack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthStackScreen} />
            
            ) 
            }
        </AppStack.Navigator>
    );
```

LoadingScreen will appear just the first seconds

MainStackScreen is another screen in which I have a bottom tab navigator with the main screen

```
    const MainStack = createBottomTabNavigator()
       <MainStack.Navigator tabBarOptions={tabBarOptions} screenOptions={screenOptions}>
            <MainStack.Screen name="Exercises" component={**ExercisesScreen**} />
            <MainStack.Screen name="Measurements" component={MeasurementsScreen} />
            <MainStack.Screen name="Workout" component={MeasurementsScreen} />
            <MainStack.Screen name="Progresses" component={ProgressesScreen} />
            <MainStack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
        </MainStack.Navigator>
```

AuthStackScreen is another screen in which I have another stack navigator that contains the signup and the signin screens

```
 const AuthStack = createStackNavigator()

    return (
        <AuthStack.Navigator headerMode="none">
            <AuthStack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen}/>
            <AuthStack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen}/>
        </AuthStack.Navigator>
    );
```

But what if I want to create other screens to navigate in from **ExercisesScreen** or another screen?
I need to create another navigator to handle them but I don't know how to insert it in these navigations that I created.

Comment: If you're on `ExercisesScreen` you can navigate to the other screens in the `MainStack` navigator. If you want `Exercises` to render another navigator you can pass that navigator component via the `Component` prop of a `MainStack.Screen` in the same way you passed a navigator component to `AuthStackScreen` and `MainStackScreen`.

Comment: But the MainstackScreen is a bottom tab navigator, this means that if I add another screen to it it will appear in the bottom bar, but I just want to handle the navigation without showing it down.

Comment: You could attach a ref to your `NavigationContainer` and use that ref to navigate from whatever screen you want like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62944296/9098350). You might also want to create an extra navigator to put the other screen in. Or you could make it a screen of `AppStack`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this, in the Main navigator I replaced ExercisesScreen with FirstScreenNavigator

```
       <MainStack.Screen name="Exercises" component={FirstScreenNavigator} />
```

and I Created a FirstScreenNavigator.js that contains

```
const FirstScreenNavigator = () => {
    return(
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen 
                name="Screen1"
                component={Screen1}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
                name="Screen2"
                component={Screen2}
            />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}
export {FirstScreenNavigator}
```

Now when I open the ExercisesScreen on the BottomTabNavigator I can easily navigate to the screens that I add into FirstScreenNavigator.js.

Many thanks to Bas Van Der Linden for the suggestions